# How do I take door hinges that have a pivot ending with two flat cylinders apart?

Tags: doors, hinges

I found a door with a pair of hinges that look like most ordinary door hinges but don't let the door to be taken off the doorpost. They seem to have a pivot that passes through the whole height of a hinge and has thick flat cylinders on each end - each has diameter of about 8 millimeters and height of about 3 millimeters.

I decided those were nuts that could be unscrewed and tried to grab them with pliers and turn counter-clockwise, but they don't seem to react, I only scratched them.

Detaching those hinges from both the door and the doorpost is not an option - I need to take them apart to apply graphite grease to them.

How do I take those hinges apart?

Comment: Can you post a picture? If the hinges are what I expect them to be I don't think you can take them apart, only unscrew them from the door and/or frame.

Comment: is there a small hole in the center of the bottom of the disk, or are they completely solid?

Comment: I'd guess they do screw apart--unless they were riveted into place. How did they get there in the first place? Perhaps they are very stuck (in which case penetrating oil might help).

Comment: @shirlock homes: There're no observable holes - both disks are solid.

Comment: A photo eould help a lot here. It isn't uncommon for hinges to have a "dummy" pin head at the bottom, for example.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot get them apart, try spraying the hinge pivot with dry silicone spray. Do not use oil based products such as WD40 or PB Blaster, as they will stain and turn black with collected dirt.  Spray with silicone, work the hinge and repeat. Hopefully it will work it's way into the pin and quiet your hinge.  Good Luck